# How to display a string representing an XML in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 website i have the following scenario:

When user clicks on a button, it calls an JsonResult that returns a string representing a XML. but when i try to displey it on a div, i get just the node values of this string.

```
<div id="xmlContent"/>

<script language="javascript">
function CustomButtonClick(s, e) {
    var gridKey = s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);
    if (e.buttonID === 'btnShowXmlContent') {

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetXmlContent")', { gridKey: gridKey }, function (data)    { 

            alert(data);
            $('#xmlContent').html(data);
            pcXmlContent.Show();
        });
    };       
 }    
 </script>
```

The plain XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>   
 <HEADER>
    <NumeroOperacao>201406030927460355</NumeroOperacao>        
  </HEADER>
  <MESSAGE>
    <ERROR>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</ERROR>
  </MESSAGE>
```

The HTML version of this xml:

```
 201406030927460355
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I would like to know how can i display this xml as plain xml?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `html()` function accepts HTML, since XML *looks* like HTML (and the browser doesn't mind) it will create `HEADER` and `NumeroOperacao` etc. as HTML nodes, which leaves just the textnodes visible.

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to add the value as text.

Comment: Thanks, i tried and it almost work, but i get the XML unformated, i mean, i have the tags on the same line, without breaking lines per node like in the original XML file that i posted on the OP.

Comment: Add `style="white-space: pre;"` to the element to preserve whitespace.